# Disabling animations to speed up a system

Tags: 14.04

My laptop is quite old and slow. I think disabling animations would speed the system, no? Chromium is especially slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `xubuntu-desktop` and some `xfce4` packages to be able to boot into a XFCE session.

```
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

   sudo apt-get install xfce4*
```

Reboot and choose the xfce session at login prompt. It would be like running Xubuntu 14.04 which is a lightweight version of Ubuntu. And you can also run the usual gnome session and disable whatever you think is worth disabling.

Comment: thanks. are there any caveats in doing so? will it be really faster? and what do you mean by "usual gnome session"? thanks again.

Comment: Use Synaptic to install xubuntu-desktop and also most of the xfce4 packages that you think you'll be needing. Don't forget to also install xfce-goodies package so you be able to customize your panels. And you can also install all lxde packages, including the actual 88lxde**

Comment: What I meant before was that you can also boot into the lxde session which is even lighter that the xfce session if you install all lxde packages and also lubuntu-desktop package.